# GetValue/SetValue Command + Do While Loop in Google Sheet File?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have written a 'for loop' (see below) to get values from an order entry sheet under a tab called 'POTemplate' in the Google Sheets file I am working with.  It seems to get, and set, variables just fine until it gets to the skuNO variable.  It returns a blank cell value into the target Sheet entitled POHistory.

```
function Submit() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var activeSheet = 
app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("POTemplate");
  for(var i = 24; i<= 34; i++) {
    var poNO = activeSheet.getRange("h2").getValue();
    var poDate = activeSheet.getRange("h3").getValue();
    var skuNo = activeSheet.getRange(i, 3).getValue();
    var skuDesc = activeSheet.getRange(i, 4).getValue();
    var qty = activeSheet.getRange(i, 5).getValue();
    var uom = activeSheet.getRange(i, 6).getValue();
    var utCost = activeSheet.getRange(i, 7).getValue();
    var extCost = activeSheet.getRange(i, 8).getValue();
    var targetSheet = 
 app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("POHistory");}
         targetSheet.getRange('a2').setValue(poNO);
         targetSheet.getRange('b2').setValue(poDate);
         targetSheet.getRange('c2').setValue(skuNo);
         targetSheet.getRange('d2').setValue(skuDesc);
         targetSheet.getRange('e2').setValue(qty);
         targetSheet.getRange('f2').setValue(uom);
         targetSheet.getRange('g2').setValue(utCost);
         targetSheet.getRange('h2').setValue(extCost);
}
```

Comment: Why not a simple for loop? `for(var i = 24, i<= 34, i++)` and then you access the stuff with `activeSheet.getRange(i, 3).getValue()`

Comment: Great suggestion, this works great...just need help now determining how to set values in the POHistory tabs with the values we've just gotten.  Thanks for your help.  They will go in LastRow + 1 in my POHistory tab.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to simply copy the cells over, `copyTo` may be useful. If you want to add additional information as well, then `appendRow` will be helpful. If you have many cells to operate on, the batch methods `getValues()` and `setValues()` will be very helpful.

```
var numCols =  8 -  3 + 1;
var numRows = 34 - 24 + 1;
var vals = activeSheet.getRange(24, 3, numRows, numCols).getValues();
/* 
 * vals = [ [skuNo1, skuDesc1, qty1, uom1, utCost1, extCost1],
 *          [skuNo2, ...] ]
 *
 * Add code that does stuff with / to vals, like using 
 * Array.unshift() to insert a value at the start of a given row,
 * or constructing a new array based on vals but with different element orders,
 * some omitted elements, new elements, etc.
 */
var targetColStart = 1; // Column A
var targetRowStart = targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
// Select a range having the same size as the `vals` array of arrays.
// (Or whichever array of arrays is to be batch-printed.)
targetSheet.getRange(targetRowStart, targetColStart, vals.length, vals[0].length)
   .setValues(vals);
```